# Cordova camera plugin permission denial in android 6.0.1

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, android-permissions

I am having the same issue as in
[Cordova camera plugin permission denial in android 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36450559/cordova-camera-plugin-permission-denial-in-android-6-0) with below error

```
Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE flg=0x3 cmp=com.sec.android.app.camera/.Camera VirtualScreenParam=Params{mDisplayId=-1, null, mFlags=0x00000000)} clip={text/uri-list U:file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.microsoft.dynamics365.operations.mobile/cache/.Pic.jpg} (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{2da888 23552:com.microsoft.dynamics365.operations.mobile/u0a70} (pid=23552, uid=10070) with revoked permission android.permission.CAMERA
```

It is Cordova hybrid app ionic framework. Below are the versions

cordova version: 6.3.1, 
cordova-plugin-camera 2.1.1 "Camera", 
android version 6.0.1.

Comment: can you try with 2.3.1 version?

Comment: It worked. Is there a way with out upgrading using the build settings?

Comment: Have you added permission for camera access in Android Manifest File. If not, then you have to add

Comment: This is an hybrid app so I cannot directly add in manifest file. Correct me if I am wrong. I am looking for a way to add in manifest file.